# How can I fill the null values like the up results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example, I have a table like below:

```
Plan    Name
211 - SELET HIAG    TEST1
NULL    TEST2
NULL    TEST3
NULL    TEST4
NULL    TEST5
213 - SOUND III TEST6
NULL    TEST7
NULL    TEST8
NULL    TEST9
211 - BUBBLE    TEST10
NULL    TEST11
NULL    TEST12
NULL    TEST13
NULL    TEST14
```

but it should be like this:

```
Plan    Name
211 - SELET HIAG    TEST1
211 - SELET HIAG    TEST2
211 - SELET HIAG    TEST3
211 - SELET HIAG    TEST4
211 - SELET HIAG    TEST5
213 - SOUND III TEST6
213 - SOUND III TEST7
213 - SOUND III TEST8
213 - SOUND III TEST9
211 - BUBBLE    TEST10
211 - BUBBLE    TEST11
211 - BUBBLE    TEST12
211 - BUBBLE    TEST13
211 - BUBBLE    TEST14
```

Ps: I have no one identity column

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `apply`, assuming you have a column specifying the ordering:

```
select tprev.plan, t.name
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.plan is not null and tprev.?? <= t.??
      order by tprev.?? desc
     ) tprev;
```

The `??` is for the column that specifies the ordering.